# How to Link to a Record View?

Tags: visualforce, opportunity, standard-objects, global-actions

Is there a way I can make an `Opportunity` hyperlink? In the code below, I want the user be able to click and view their own `Opportunity` records.

**Extension**

```
public with sharing class OppExt {
     public List<Opportunity> myOpportunities { get; private set; }

     public OppExt(){
         myOpportunities = [ SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name
                 from Opportunity 
                 WHERE OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

    }
}
```

**Page Snippet**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!myOpportunities}" var="opp" >
    <apex:outputText value="{!opp.Name}"/><br/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: look at this documentation on apex:outputlink : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputLink.htm

Comment: Have you read through the visual force developers guide? Or the online reference. You will stumble upon a component <apex:commandLink> or <apex:outPutLink> that will do what you wish

Comment: @Rao how do you add specific opportunity ID as hyperlink?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So @Monith's answer is correct in that you should use an `outputLink` tag, but I disagree with the link construction methodology enough to post a separate answer.

When you are constructing links for standard actions, you should use the `$Action` global variable:

```
{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.View, opportunity.Id)}
```

If you look through the [Valid Values for the $Action Global Variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action_valid_values.htm), you will see many that you can use with `Opportunity`:

- `AddInfluence`
- `Clone`
- `Delete`
- `List`
- `New`
- `Share`
- `Submit for Approval` (not sure how the syntax works there...should probably be `Submit`)
- `View`

Comment: What does New do?

Comment: That would create a new record, so you would not pass an Id in there.

Comment: when the record is dynamic and we only have the id (e.g. for viewing the parent attachment, it can be account, case, etc) how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use apex:outputlink for same

```
<apex:repeat value="{!myOpportunities}" var="opp" >
        <apex:outputlink value="/{!opp.Id}">{!opp.Name}</apex:outputlink><br/>
 </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend using standard view actions instead of rolling your own link. `{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.View, opp.Id)}`

Comment: @AdrianLarson Besides Edit and View is there anything else available Opportunity.View for opportunity?

Comment: Take a look at `VisualForce` [Global Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global.htm), specifically the `$Action` [variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action.htm).

Comment: `Opportunity` has many [valid values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action_valid_values.htm).